# Load Facebook Sharer in iFrame

Tags: facebook

I'm just trying to load the facebook sharer page into an iframe which is in a positioned div with no success.

Here is the code I'm using for the iframe,

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.website.com&t=Title Hoes Here"></iframe>
```

When I view the page its blank and the iframe source is

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.website.com&t=Title Hoes Here">
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

If I view the url directly, everything appears properly.

Does facebook block loading the sharer in an iFrame? and what are my alternatives to have the facebook sharer appear in a modal window?

Thanks

Comment: You should not be using a deprecated function in new development.  It's unsupported and will be pulled out from under us at any time.  Please see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ for more information on what you should do.

Comment: Almost 9 years after, `sharer.php` is still supported.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Facebook pretty much blocks all loading of screens inside of iFrames.

If you are using Facebook connect there is some simple javascript methods you can execute to get a dialog on your page, and to boot Facebook will take care a lot of the work it takes to make the screen look nice.

See this link ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/ ) or use the code below:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

If you are not using Facebook connect then really your only option to get that exact screen is to throw a pop-up.

Another option would be to use the like/send button plugin, this isn't quite the same functionality but is easier to integrate. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Cheers!

Comment: F@#$ facebook, twitter, linked in, pinterest and all the rest who want to spy on your users and make your pages load slow. None of them allow for loading their stuff only if the user wants to use the service. I wanted it to look nice in an iFrame but they won't allow it. Google Plus is the only one who will allow an iframe.

Comment: @pathfinder: Yes, did some research too and load the social media trash only when user click on it. On this site http://meezingeninrotterdam.nl (which it's event is closed now) you can see how i have done it. Click on the facebook icon for example, it will ask you to confirm third-party cookies. After this the addthis plugin will be loaded if you decide to continue. This method saves the user alot of traffic and users can be followed only when you have accepted the third-party cookie dialog. This method saves you also the need to add an cookie policy banner FOR ALL users on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The above line in the head.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : '',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});
};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').live('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{

method: 'feed',
name: '',
link: '',
picture: '',
caption: '',
description: '',
message: ''
});
});
});
</script>
```